# Bounding box is misaligned after object detection by converting yolov5 to TFLite type ＆ About obtaining labels

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-imaging-library, tensorflow-lite, yolo

We converted yolov5 to TensorFlowLite type and created a program to perform object detection from images.
However, when looking at the output image, all bounding boxes are displayed slightly lower to the right than the target object.
I am trying to fix this but am completely stuck.

The conversion to TensorFlowLite and the object detection program we implemented this time are as follows.
In addition, the execution environment is GoogleColaboratory.

**Conversion of yolov5 to TensorFlowLite**

1. clone from GitHub (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git)
   Also install necessary packages using requirements.t
2. convert to TFLite with the following command
   `python export.py --weights yolov5m.pt --img 640 --include tflite`
3. As a result of the execution, the following tflite format file was created.
   `/content/yolov5/yolov5m-fp16.tflite`

**Source code for object detection**
The final output is an image with bounding boxes drawn.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import tensorflow as tf
import time

model_path = '/content/yolov5/yolov5m-fp16.tflite'

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Image Preparation
image_name = 'test_picture.jpg'
image_path = f'/content/{image_name}'

image = Image.open(image_path)
image = image.resize((640, 640))
image = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32) / 255.0
image = image[np.newaxis, ...]

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image)
interpreter.invoke()

# Obtaining model output
output = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

boxes = output[..., :4]  # bounding box coordinates
confidence = output[..., 4:5]  # credibility
class_probs = output[..., 5:]  # class probability

# Threshold setting
confidence_threshold = 0.5

detections = []
for i in range(len(output)):
    for j in range(output.shape[1]):
        if confidence[i][j] > confidence_threshold:
            # Add class probability, class ID, and bounding box coordinate information to the list
            x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = boxes[i][j]
            class_probabilities = class_probs[i][j]
            class_id = np.argmax(class_probabilities)
            detections.append([confidence[i][j], class_id, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max])

# Create font object
font_path = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf"
font_size = 12
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)

# Converted to Pillow Image object
image_pil = Image.fromarray((image[0] * 255).astype('uint8'))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_pil)

for detection in detections:
    confidence, class_id, x, y, width, height = detection

    # Calculate coordinates of bounding box
    left = int(x * image_pil.width)
    top = int(y * image_pil.height)
    right = int((x + width) * image_pil.width)
    bottom = int((y + height) * image_pil.height)

    # Drawing bounding boxes
    color = (255, 0, 0)
    thickness = 1
    draw.rectangle([left, top, right, bottom], outline=color, width=thickness)

    label = labels.get(class_id, "Unknown")
    text_color = (255, 0, 0)
    text_position = (left, top-15)
    draw.text(text_position, label, fill=text_color, font=font)

output_image_path = f'/content/output/{image_name}_detection.jpg'
# Saving Images
image_pil.save(output_image_path)
```

The above is the code used in this project.

**I have one more question.**
The last part of the above code uses the variable labels.
The contents of the LABELS, which I will not go into because they are lengthy, are as follows.

```
labels = {
  0: 'person',
  1: 'bicycle',
  2: 'car',
・・・
  78: 'hair drier',
  79: 'toothbrush',
}
```

This label was copied and pasted from the contents of the following yaml file.
`/content/yolov5/data/coco.yaml`

Is there any way to use labels from these datasets when using yolov5 converted to TensorFlowLite?

Currently, no errors are output and object detection seems to be working well.
However, when drawing the bounding box, the coordinates are not set properly and the object is displayed slightly lower to the right than the target object.
(So sorry, can't do the picture due to rights reasons.)
I tried to mess around with the coordinates part, but it didn't work.
Please tell me how to improve it.